# Proportionally size an imageview in Android

Tags: android, imageview, scale

Suppose you have this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mylogo_250px60px"
/>
```

I would like to define height so it scales accordingly to width. So if Android decides to scale logo to be shown in width, height should increase as well.

Is it also possible to define something, so when the phone is tilted from vertical to horizontal, the logo will scale correctly?

(Basically, the logo is above a listview on the main activity)

I have also tried using this, but no luck (the height appears much to low compared to width. Image is not resized/scaled in height)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mylogo_250px60px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"                                       
    />
```

If I design it in Eclipse/ADT gui tool logo gets 76dp and looks good on my two test phones. However, I think it should be possible to simply scale image propertionally?

**"fixed height" has correct rato to width** (vertical view, not when phone is tilted)
[image]

**"auto height" appears wrong ratio wise compared to width:**
[image]

Comment: could you please show us the output image to us?

Comment: Okay. I will upload 76dp height version + suggested change that does not appear to be working

Comment: I have uploaded two screenshots now. I guess I could use the fixed, but I would prefer to use a configuration where the image would auto resize and scale correctly no matter what

Comment: please show us the image with expected output

Comment: That is screenshot number 1. That is how I want it to look. (True/correct ratios) I can only achieve that by using fixed dp height which is problematic, e.g. when the phone is tilted to horizontal view

Answer (score 11):

Change your imageview code as below

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mylogo_250px60px"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the height continues to be tiny (not resized/scaled) with width stretched to match parent width.

Comment: if it is possible to make 9-patch drawable for your image you can try that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mylogo_250px60px"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
```

hope its help

Comment: With an 9 patch image android:adjustViewBounds is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mylogo_250px60px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                      
/>
```

The only problem: The drawable must be at least as wide as its parent.

The rendering won't let the ImageView be wider than its parent:

- So it will fit exactly in width
- And it will keep proportional (because of the wrap_content)

I usually calculate for a phone with a resolution of 1080x1092 (fullHD).